# How do I find the point on a given hyperbola that passes through a given point not on the hyperbola?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, tangent-line

There's a family of lines and where they intersect, the envelope, is a hyperbola. The hyperbola's center is at the origin and the $y$-axis is its axis of symmetry, and I know both $a$ and $b$. I'm also given an arbitrary point $(x_1, y_1)$ that lies on one of the lines but does NOT lie on the hyperbola. What I have to find is the point (points?) $(x_2, y_2)$ that lies on that same line, but also DOES lie on the
hyperbola. In other words, the point at which the line through $(x_1, y_1)$ is tangent to the hyperbola. How?

I've searched, without luck, for an equation that takes a point on such a line and the hyperbola's equation, and gives the tangent point. I do have the equation for the line tangent to the hyperbola at $(x_2, y_2)$, which I thought I could work backwards to find the tangent point, but I've lost my way. All help is appreciated!

Comment: Work out the general equation of the tangent to the hyperbola and solve for its intersection with the given point. Once this is known the point lying on the hyperbola itself should be straightforward to obtain.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. If you plan to come again, please do learn MathJax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If
$$
{x^2\over a^2}-{y^2\over b^2}=1
$$
is the equation of the hyperbola, then
$$
{xx_1\over a^2}-{yy_1\over b^2}=1
$$
is the equation of the line through the tangency points, for the tangents issued from $(x_1,y_1)$ (see [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/JoachimsthalsNotations.shtml) for a proof).

The solutions of the system formed by these equations will then give the coordinates of the required tangency points.